# How to show value bottom of angular gauge chart in fusion chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fusioncharts

I'm trying to find option to show `dial` value at the bottom of angular gauge chart. I'm using fusion charts XT. I don't find any option to show dial value at different places. By default it's showing in the middle of angular gauge chart.

**Refer below Images**

[image: Angular Gauge]

You can see in left image, I want dial value which is 87 at the bottom of the chart. Also I'm trying to achieve gradient color of gauge chart same as image you can see at the right side. I'm trying to understand how `gaugeFillMix` and `gaugeFillRatio` works.

Here is [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/577w5/45/) on which I'm working.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

To show value below the dial you can use the "valueBelowPivot" attribute and set it to 1.
Refer fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/moonmi/577w5/46/

```
            "valueBelowPivot":"1"
```

For gaugeFillMix and fillRatio you can check out the gauges from FusionCharts gallery, where you can find the json/xml of the chart.

Link: http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/gauges/

Hope this would help.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please help me with gradient color for gauge. Also, Can we reduce the font-size of this dial value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
"valueBelowPivot": "1",
```

Refer the [document](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/gauges-and-widgets/angular-gauge#configure-the-gauge-gradient-fill) to achieve gradient color of gauge chart

Check the sample code reference [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9k75cq2/2/)